# how to change color based on different stock status value how can we do onload

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.productList}" var="item" >
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-around_small">
                                    <lightning:card title="">
                                        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small ">
                                            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                                                    <img src="{!$Resource}"/>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3" >
                                                    <lightning:button variant="base" onclick="{!c.showDetails}" name="{!item.objData.Product2.Id}"  value=""><h1><b><u>{!item.objData.Product2.Name}</u></b> </h1></lightning:button> <br/>
                                                    <h2>ISBN&nbsp;:&nbsp;{!item.objData.Product2.ISBN__c}</h2>
                                                    <h2>Series&nbsp;:&nbsp;{!item.objData.Product2.S__c}</h2>
                                                    <h2>Amount&nbsp;:&nbsp;{!item.objData.UnitPrice}</h2>


                                                        <h2 >Stock Status &nbsp;:&nbsp;{!item.objData.Product2.Stock_Status__c}</h2>
                                                        <span class="slds-icon_container  slds-icon_container--circle" style="background-color:Green;">

                                                        </span>



                                                    <h2>Author&nbsp;:&nbsp;{!item.objData.Product2.Author_Name__c}</h2>

                                                    <div>
                                                        <lightning:button name="{!item.objData.Id}"   variant="brand" label="Add Cart"
                                                                          disabled="{!v.buttonDiasble}"
                                                                          value="Add Cart"
                                                                          onclick="{!c.addtoCart}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>      
                                        </p>

                                    </lightning:card>
                                </div>
                            </aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the style conditionally/dynamically
instead of

```
<span class="slds-icon_container  slds-icon_container--circle" style="background-color:Green;">
```

you can use like this

```
  <span class="slds-icon_container  slds-icon_container--circle" 
style="{!item.objData.Product2.Stock_Status__c =='High Stock' ? 'background-color:Red;': 'background-color:Green;' }">
```

Like this, you can make the dynamic styling. 
Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

1 more possible way to do it by using wrapper class in apex by adding 1 more variable "StockColor" giving value with Color Name and we can iterate for productList and use it in component for showing different color.

Code:

```
<h2>Stock Status &nbsp;:&nbsp;{!item.objData.Product2.Stock_Status__c}</h2>
<span class="slds-icon_container  slds-icon_container--circle" style="background-color:{!item.objData.StockColor};"></span>
```